# How to Change Text Color in ApexCharts Label?

Tags: javascript, tooltip, apexcharts

How can I change the text color of an ApexCharts tooltip/label? The problem is the font color is too dark:

[image]

I've tried for the life of me reading through the ApexCharts docs for a solution, but all I could find was:

```
chart: {
    foreColor: '#ffffff'
}
```

I tried it on my chart, but it had no effect.

Here are the complete settings for my chart:

```
var colors = [ "#008ffb", "#ffc300", "#0acf97", "#fa5c7c", "#e3eaef" ];
var options = {
        chart: {
            foreColor: '#ffffff',
            height: 412,
            type: "pie",
            toolbar: {
                show: true
            }
        },
        series: [ 9890571, 5276166, 4810254, 3823869, 3463197 ],
        labels: [ "CHINO DEVELOPMENT COMPANY", "SC DEVELOPMENT COMPANY, LLC", "RICHLAND, INC.", "SL DEVELOPMENT COMPANY, LLC", "BROOKCAL, LLC" ],
        colors: colors,
        legend: {
            show: !0,
            position: "bottom",
            horizontalAlign: "center",
            verticalAlign: "middle",
            floating: !1,
            fontSize: "14px",
            offsetX: 0,
            offsetY: 7
        },
        responsive: [{
            breakpoint: 600,
            options: {
                chart: {
                    height: 240
                },
                legend: {
                    show: !1
                }
            }
        }]
    },
    chart = new ApexCharts(document.querySelector("#simple-pie"), options);
chart.render();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following CSS worked for me:

```
.apexcharts-tooltip span {
    color: #ffffff;
}
```

Someone earlier had suggested a similar answer but had omitted the span selector. Without span, it doesn't work for me.